# Use Python and OpenCV to merge these two images of cropped skin and original selfie?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So, the idea is to merge these two pictures together. [image: Whitened Cropped Skin Only] and [image: Original Selfie].

Now what I've tried is the following:

```
img1 = cv2.imread("/home/victor/GammaAdjustedImage.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("/home/victor/VE/OriginalSelfie.jpg")

dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 0.5 , img2, 0.4, 0)

cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, unfortunately for me, the code produced the following error:

error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

The first picture is as the title says, the facial skin which I cropped out through the use of dlib, opencv and convexhull, and numpy and whitened it through gamma correction.

The second one is the original image. How do I combine the two images such that the second one will stay invariably the same, but have the whitened skin of the first one? Thank you!

Note: The eyes, lips, and eyebrows of the second image must stay exactly as they are (shouldn't be blacked out as in the first image). What I simply want is to somehow paste the whitened skin onto the second image. Everything else stays exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

Usually you get that error when trying to **add images that have different shapes** (channels, size).

You can verify the shape of your images by doing `img.shape` which returns something like `(100,100,3)` (meaning a 100X100, 3-channel image). Surely your two images do not have the same shape.

To overcome this issue you must only add images that have the same shapes. If the selfie and the adjusted image don't have the same shape, you must **obtain and operate on a Region of Interest (ROI)** of the biggest image that matches exactly the shape of the smaller image to operate.

To obtain a ROI from your `img2` you can use Python Slicing, something like `roi = img2[0:50, 0:50]` (obtaining a 50 by 50 region starting from the origin of the image).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. What I've attempted just now was to use the addWeighted function, but it gave me a very bad result. The result was that the image was either too bright or too dark depending on the supplied parameters. Is ROI the best way to handle such a task or are there alternatives?

Comment: @VictorSimon without seeing the result hard to tell (add it to your post of you may). Addweighted and add are different, when I see the result I may be able to help more. ROI is the only way of your images have different sizes, so you can male them both equal (that or make the smaller img bigger)

Answer (score 0):

AddWeighted is not the correct solution. You want to a straight "over" composite function. I've thrown something together to demonstrate:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#convert to float to make things easier
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.jpg"),-1)
img1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg"),-1)
img1 = img1.astype('float')
img2 = img2.astype('float')
img1/=255
img2/=255

#mask a mask based on the black or white pixels
#all black and white pixels become black in the mask
#everything else becomes white
mask = np.copy(img1)
b,g,r = cv2.split(mask)
mask = (b+g+r)/3
#using .2 and .9 because there are compression artifacts in the image
mask[mask>=.9] = 0
mask[mask<=.2] = 0
mask[mask!=0] = 1

#making mask 3 channels to make composite easier
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])
#over operation = (img1*alpha) + (background*(1-alpha))
output = (img1*mask) + (img2*(1-mask))
```

[image: output image]

The output is still terrible. Why:

- Mask is inaccurate
- Mask should blend on the edges to smooth the
  transition. This can be done with an erode filter followed by a blur
  filter. You should use large kernel sizes 11 to 21, possibly larger, depending on your input image size.
- Your gamma adjustment is much too strong.